# What is PostLogoutRedirectUris and signout-callback-oidc in signout flow

Tags: identityserver4

what is the purpose of
`PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://yourclienthost:port/signout-callback-oidc" }`
in Client Config please?

When I put it, IdentityServer logout page show confirmed logout message ***AND*** shows a link to redirect back to my application.
[image]

When I omit it, IdentityServer show confirmed logout message ***BUT NOT*** shows a link to redirect back to my application
[image]

Regardless of the options, IdentityServer ***still logs me out***. So I am confused what that config does. Please help clarify. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of PostLogoutRedirectUris in client config is security.

When the client initiates signout, the client opens a url like that:

1. https://[identity-server]/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=**https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Fapp%2Fsignout-callback-oidc**&id_token_hint=XXX&state=YYY&...

Pay attention that the client itself tells IdentityServer where to redirect to after signout. This means that the client might cheat IdentityServer to redirect to a malicious URI.
That's why a white-list of URIs is used on the IdentityServer side, which is called `PostLogoutRedirectUris`. The list contains all possible deployment locations of the client e.g.

```
"PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
    "https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc",
    "https://client/app/signout-callback-oidc", ...
]
```

When the callback URI suggested by the client is not on the white-list, then

> IdentityServer shows confirmed logout message but NOT a link to
> redirect back to your application

The signout process continues like that:

2. .../connect/endsession above redirects to `https://[identity-server]/Account/Logout?logoutId=ZZZ`
3. The Logout action renders a page with the link back to the client ( `https://client/app/signout-callback-oidc&id_token_hint=XXX&state=YYY&...` )
4. On the same page there is also an iframe wich opens `https://[identity-server]/connect/endsession/callback?endSessionId=TTT`
5. This iframe renders another iframe which signs out the client by calling `https://client/app/signout-oidc?sid=SSS&iss=https://identity-server`
6. On the same page there is also some JavaScript which automatically opens the link from step 3 and goes back to your client app.
7. The `/signout-callback-oidc` route in a MVC client does nothing (probably; I don't know what it does) but it redirects to the home page. (*)

The signout from both IdentityServer and the client app is already **complete in step 5**. `/signout-callback-oidc` has nothing to do with the signout itself. It only provides a landing page back in the client app so that the user does not get stuck on a page in IdentityServer.

(*) More precisely, `/signout-callback-oidc` in the client app redirects to `options.SignedOutRedirectUri` which can be set during `AddOpenIdConnect()`.
By defaut `SignedOutRedirectUri == "/"`. I prefer to change that option to `"/Account/Login"`. In this way I see the login page right after signout.

`"/signout-callback-oidc"` is just the default value of `options.SignedOutCallbackPath`. You can change that path but there is no benefit. This route is automatically registered and automatically handled by the middleware. You cannot write your own controller/action for that route.

Comment: Beautiful answer

Answer (score 2):

`PostLogoutRedirectUri` is meant to redirect you when you log out of your client. It will, e.g. bring you back to your client application's home screen. When you implement a 'single' logout for your application, you stay logged in to IdentityServer.

Once you are logged out of IdentityServer itself however, no `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is used and the flow ends on the IdentityServer UI.

In this case, it probably means that you implemented your signout by calling `SignOutAsync` twice. Once for the local application and once for the IDP but I can't be sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to ask "is meant to redirect you when you log out of your client. It will, e.g. bring you back to your client application's home screen" isn't this for SignedOutRedirectUri option in AddOpenIdConnect middleware? E.g. if I put option.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/say-goodbye-after-logout" then it would redirect me to that path. Not the same for PostLogoutRedirectUri though.

Comment: Well, yes. Where exactly you take your user after logout is your choice. That's why `PostLogoutRedirectUri` is often a virtual URL e.g. `yourapplication/signout-callback-oidc`.
Your implementation of where you take a user post logout is your choice. Identity providers just point to your application to make sure the flow doesn't end at the identity provider (because that would be meaningless).